# How do I keep a VideoView fragment undisturbed while using tabs and swipes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

Preface: The app I am developing is only targeting versions 4.0 and higher.

I've been using Eclipse with the Android SDK for about 5 weeks. I've created a fairly complex activity with fragments. The main fragments are a listview and videoview. I am using a dynamic layout for tablets, phones and landscape versus portrait.

Right now everything is just the way I want it and now it is time to move beyond my proof of concept.

I am developing a music/video app and I have successfully coded my videoview (it is playing both video and audio) to be minimizable. This is working perfectly.

My challenge:

I want to integrate tabs & tab-swipes. My main activity is a relative layout with nested framelayouts to inflate the listview and videoview and a few other views.

I have found a very simple and straightforward example of using the tabs & tab swipes:

https://github.com/posco2k8/fragment_tabs_tutorial

It basically swaps out fragments when clicking different tabs or swiping.

What I wish to accomplish is this:

1. I want my videoview player when minimized to remain visible irregardless of the active tab.
2. I would like to understand better how to take my current activity_main.xml that has a relativelayout with nested framelayouts, etc. and adapt it to use the tab/swipe paradigm.

Here is my activity_main.xml that I somehow need to refactor to support the above specs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="#404040"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movingAlong"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/gemstersmall"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </ImageView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/strut"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playa_views"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/playerfragment"
            android:name="com.radiodile.mobile.PlayerFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/other_views"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playerEventDisplay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/listitemheader"
            android:name="com.radiodile.mobile.ListViewHeaderSearchType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#909090"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/listitemvideo"
            android:name="com.radiodile.mobile.VideosListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/listitemfooter"
            android:name="com.radiodile.mobile.ListViewFooterFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/listitemfootersuggestions"
            android:name="com.radiodile.mobile.ListViewFooterFragmentSuggestions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks very much!!

Comment: I know it's late. Take a look at [DraggablePanel](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel), maybe it is what you're looking for?